# Changing the order of fields on a form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a simple form with a handful of data entry fields on it. Is there a way to change the order of the fields each time the form is displayed? So user 1 sees Fieldb,FieldC,FieldA, then user 2 sees FieldA,FieldB,FieldC and so on?

*UPDATE: My first thought was to call the fields from a lookup table:

```
Me.lbl_a.Caption = DLookup("Label", "Lkup")
Me.Field_A.ControlSource = DLookup("Field", "Lkup")
```

These basic dlookups just pull the top row from my table, not sure how to call all of my fields and in a different order each time.
Any advice? Sorry for the vague language.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do here.. you say you want the order of the fields to change, but then you give an example of 2 users seeing the fields in the exact same order. What does it say in the Default View property of your form? Single Form? Continuous? Datasheet?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Two users see different things now. I came up with something similar to Gustav's code below that is doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change the ControlSource for the controls in question:

User 1 wanting field1 for first control:

```
Me!lbl_a.Caption = "Caption for Field1"
Me!Field_A.ControlSource = "Field1"
```

User 2 wanting field7 for first control:

```
Me!lbl_a.Caption = "Caption for Field7"
Me!Field_A.ControlSource = "Field7"
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. And I have the field names in a lookup table that randomizes the fields so each user sees a different order.